# Procedure or function SP_XXX has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

im working on some project and got this error msg :

*Procedure or function SP_XXX has too many arguments specified*
below are my SQL parameter im passing through ASP c# App
checked many sites and got nothing :)
Thanks a lot for your help!

```
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.CODE, ParameterName = "@CODE" });cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = CODE, ParameterName = "@OLD_CODE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = COCODE, ParameterName = "@OLD_COCODE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.COCODE, ParameterName = "@COCODE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.MEMBERTYPE, ParameterName = "@MEMBERTYPE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.ENNAME, ParameterName = "@ENNAME" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.ARNAME, ParameterName = "@ARNAME" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.NATIONALITY, ParameterName = "@NATIONALITY" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.GENDER, ParameterName = "@GENDER" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.SPECIAL, ParameterName = "@SPECIAL" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = (object)user.BIRTHDATE ?? DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@BIRTHDATE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.Religion, ParameterName = "@RELIGION" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.QUALIFY, ParameterName = "@QUALIFY" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.MEMBERPOS, ParameterName = "@MEMBERPOS" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = (object)user.JOINDATE ?? DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@JOINDATE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = (object)user.EXPIRYDATE ?? DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@EXPIRYDATE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.POBOX, ParameterName = "@POBOX" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.WORKTEL, ParameterName = "@WORKTEL" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.HOMETEL, ParameterName = "@HOMETEL" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.MOBILE, ParameterName = "@MOBILE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.FAX, ParameterName = "@FAX" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.EMAIL, ParameterName = "@EMAIL" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.WEBSITE, ParameterName = "@WEBSITE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.ACCCODE, ParameterName = "@ACCCODE" });

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.AMOUNT, ParameterName = "@AMOUNT" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.PAIDAMOUNT, ParameterName = "@PAIDAMOUNT" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.EMIRATE, ParameterName = "@EMIRATE" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.MILIT_NO, ParameterName = "@MILIT_NO" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.GRADE, ParameterName = "@GRADE" });

        //need job

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.NEEDJOB, ParameterName = "@NEEDJOB" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.DEBIT, ParameterName = "@DEBIT" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.JOBNAME, ParameterName = "@JOBNAME" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.BNKNAME, ParameterName = "@BNKNAME" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = (object)user.BNKAMOUNT ?? DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@BNKAMOUNT" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.COMPAGNY, ParameterName = "@COMPAGNY" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = (object)user.COMPAMOUNT ?? DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@COMPAMOUNT" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.PRSN, ParameterName = "@PRSN" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = (object)user.PRSNAMOUNT ?? DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@PRSNAMOUNT" });
        if (user.PIC == null)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@PIC", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Image });
        else
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.PIC, ParameterName = "@PIC" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.COMPANY, ParameterName = "@COMPANY" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.TYPEBLOOD, ParameterName = "@TYPEBLOOD" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.PASSPORTNUM, ParameterName = "@PASSPORTNUM" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.LEAVENUM, ParameterName = "@LEAVENUM" });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = user.POSBEFORE, ParameterName = "@POSBEFORE" });
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = (object)user.LEAVEDATE ?? DBNull.Value, ParameterName = "@LEAVEDATE" });
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "SP_MSMEMBERS_UPDATE";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStrings"].ToString();
        con.ConnectionString = constr;
        con.Open();
        int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
```

---

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MSMEMBERS_UPDATE] 
       (
 @CODE VARCHAR(10),
 @OLD_CODE VARCHAR(10),
 @COCODE INTEGER,
 @OLD_COCODE INTEGER,
 @MEMBERTYPE INTEGER,
 @ENNAME VARCHAR(40),
 @ARNAME VARCHAR(40),
 @NATIONALITY INTEGER,
 @GENDER VARCHAR(1),
 @SPECIAL VARCHAR(1),
 @BIRTHDATE DATETIME,
 @RELIGION INTEGER,
 @QUALIFY INTEGER,
 @MEMBERPOS VARCHAR(40),
 @JOINDATE DATETIME,
 @EXPIRYDATE DATETIME,
 @POBOX VARCHAR(15),
 @WORKTEL VARCHAR(30),
 @HOMETEL VARCHAR(30),
 @MOBILE  VARCHAR(30),
 @FAX  VARCHAR(30),
 @EMAIL VARCHAR(40),
 @WEBSITE VARCHAR(80),
 @ACCCODE VARCHAR(20),
 @AMOUNT NUMERIC(15,3),
 @PAIDAMOUNT NUMERIC(15,3),
 @EMIRATE INTEGER,
 @MILIT_NO VARCHAR(40),
 @GRADE VARCHAR(20)
 --new add
 ,@NEEDJOB VARCHAR(1) 
 ,@DEBIT VARCHAR(1)
 ,@JOBNAME varchar(20)
 ,@BNKNAME varchar(25)
 ,@BNKAMOUNT NUMERIC(15,3)
 ,@COMPAGNY nvarchar(25)
 ,@COMPAMOUNT NUMERIC(15,3)
 ,@PRSN varchar(30)
 ,@PRSNAMOUNT NUMERIC(15,3)
 ,@PIC image
 ,@COMPANY varchar(25)
 ,@TYPEBLOOD varchar(20)
 ,@PASSPORTNUM varchar(20)
 ,@LEAVENUM varchar(10)
 ,@POSBEFORE varchar(15)
 ,@LEAVEDATE datetime
)
```

Comment: Can you include your stored procedure?

Comment: The error means you're specifying more parameters in your c# code than your stored procedure accepts

Comment: Check to see if the number of parameters in your store proc are the same as the number you are assigning in your C# code

Comment: hi, I just added the SP below the parameters

Comment: I think I got this once when the datatypes of the parameters in the sp didn't match the datatypes of the table columns(or maybe the input data... its been a while).... just throwing it out there

Comment: Actually you have 44 parameter in codebehind, but in procedure you need 45 parameter.

Comment: its the same but in-case there was mssing parameter i'll get another exception with missing parameter

Answer (score 3):

sorry for the wrong post

Second of all I ran the c# code as the following:

```
public class MemberD
{
    public SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConStr");
    public SqlDataReader dr;

    public void UpdateMember(string CODE, int COCODE, Member user)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear(); // Here's  the solution

        //Here I added my SQL parameters 
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "SP_MSMEMBERS_UPDATE";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The point was that im using the SqlCommand as global variable initiated once
so when I use the Update method twice OR GetByID method for example, the SQLCommand variable keeps the old parameter as well. So when you **pass parameters more than the SP needs**  you get the above error, so simply I added:
      **cmd.Parameters.Clear();**
at the beginning of each method.

and now its working fine.

Comment: Man you have helped me a lot, I made the same mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error usually represents having more arguments than your SP has defined.

Since you haven't provided enough code to tell you for sure (provide more of the cmd codeblock and at least the definitions of the SP), I would assume it being that case. Especially with this many arguments being supplied.

I did read that this can also be a potential issue caused when dealing with SqlDatasources. However, due to your limited code provided, I'm just pointing that out as a possibility.

Comment: hi, its the same number I mean parameters in SP and APP. however im using this code in the backend cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SP_MSMEMBERS_UPDATE";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStrings"].ToString();
            con.ConnectionString = constr;
            con.Open();
            int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: the problem might be the if else statement in place, edit you code and use brackets around the if and else statement so i we know exactly where it ends

Comment: if else is ok cause im using the same code with Add method... anyway i've added the c# code with the question above